# When should "Flag" be selected in Triage over "Needs author edit"?

Tags: support, triage

Triage has been updated to use the options "Approve", "Needs community edit", "Flag", "Needs author edit", and "Skip", as opposed to "Looks OK", "Requires editing", "Unsalvageable", and "Skip".

Let's consider the following question that I quickly cobbled together for explanation purposes:

> ### I am getting an error
>
> I am getting this error:
>
> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined
> ```
>
> But I defined `variable` in the global scope on the first line of my code. Why is this happening?
>
> [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [referenceerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/referenceerror)

This question doesn't provide the code causing the error.

If you were asked to review this in Triage, should you pick "Flag > Needs improvement > A community-specific reason > Needs debugging details", or "Needs author edit"? I would pick the first one out of habit, but is the second one somehow more preferable?

Comment: They both ultimately lead to the same place. Both options exist in the interface to make it clearer to reviewers that questions that require OP's editing need a close flag. Choose whichever you wish.

Comment: @CertainPerformance So "Needs author edit" is the same as the first one, just with less clicks?

Comment: Yep, unless you want to raise a non-closure flag, might as well choose "Needs author edit"

Answer (score 4):

@CertainPerfomance has notified me in the comments that they both "ultimately [can] lead to the same place".

The only difference is that *"Needs author edit"* leads directly to the closure flags under *"Needs Improvement"*; whereas the *"Flag"* button takes you to the first screen of the flag dialog, where more options are present (as in *"Spam"*, *"Rude or Abusive"*, etc.).

Both of @CertainPerfomance's comments:

> They both ultimately lead to the same place. Both options exist in the interface to make it clearer to reviewers that questions that require OP's editing need a close flag. Choose whichever you wish

> Yep, unless you want to raise a non-closure flag, might as well choose "Needs author edit"

Comment: What is a non-closure flag that you might want to raise in the queue?